# Is there a way to have mysql client use different options group?

Tags: mysql

I know mysql client reads its options from .my.cnf in the groups [client] and [mysql]. I have other programs which use different groups and I would like to use those same groups (e.g. [appgroup]) instead of the default ones to reproduce the same connection options and act interactively as if it was the program connecting. Is there a way to do that?

Example config file:

```
[client]
user ...
pass ...

[appgroup]
user ...
pass ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to use different config files for mysql client. You can do this with command:

```
mysql --defaults-file=config1.cnf <other parameters>
```

In this case the client will read only this files AND .mylogin.cnf (usually located in your home directory)

Comment: I want to use a different section in the same file. I programmatically do that for the application and I want to have the client use that same section

Comment: @a1an, I do not get, same section or different? You can have both by using different config files and use above way

Comment: Same file, different section (or group as they call it).

Comment: @a1an, I do not think you can do this. \Just consider to use different file

Answer (score 0):

Try [`--defaults-group-suffix`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix).

You must name your sections starting with `client`, e.g.

.my.cnf

```
[client]
user=wilma
password=shhhhhh1
...

[clientBetty]
user=betty
password=neveryoumindnow
port=13306
...
```

Then call with

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=Betty
```

to access the Betty overrides. I believe they're overrides, i.e. you'll get all the stuff from `[client]`, except where a different value is specified for `[clientBetty]`.